# VueJS firstly pre-fetch data in the store vuex

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I want to pre-fetch data in my store (vuex) so I can use the data to render some component

in my store file :

```
const actions = {
    async LOAD_PROJECTS ({commit}) {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8081/blabla')
            commit('SET_PROJECTS', response.data)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error', err)
        }
    }
 }
```

and in the main component (app)

```
export default {
    async beforeCreate () {
        await this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_PROJECTS')
    }
}
```

And when I want to access the data that I freshly load:
It works in the case when I go from the main page (e.g : http://localhost:8080/#) to the page with the component (e.g : http://localhost:8080/#/component) but when I want to access directly the page with the component, it doesn't work (I already tried to put the same code in the component itself, it doesn't work)

How should I proceed it so it should work in both case?

EDIT : I want something global, like first I want to fetch the data and then...

Comment: You should create a vuex action that fetches the data you want, then stick it in your base component (usually named App). That way you can use it whenever you want assuming you pass it from the action to a mutator and into your state

Comment: Make sure your child component is actually in your app component. There shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: so instead of fetching data in vuex, I'm fetching data in the base component ? But there'll be no point in vuex who's acting like centralized store for every component, right?